# How to generate cache only once if there are multiple requests during generation

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP website to generate HTML (or maybe json) based on a large xml and a large txt. Here is my code:

```
$cachetime = filemtime(__DIR__.'/cache.html');
if ($cachetime > filemtime(__DIR__.'/source1.txt') && $cachetime > filemtime(__DIR__.'/source2.xml'))
    $content = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/cache.html");
else {
    $content = generate_content(__DIR__.'/source1.txt',__DIR__.'/source2.xml'); //takes some seconds
    $file =  fopen(__DIR__."/cache.html", "w");
    fwrite($file, $content);
    fclose($file);
}
```

The problem is that if the content generation takes some seconds and there are multiple requests to this page before the generation finish, the generation will be executed many times. I want to make sure the generation only executes at the first request and all the following requests just wait for the first generation to complete and read cache.

Comment: https://www.php.net/flock

Comment: @deceze would you please write some example code?